# Disable "get focus" for ASPxTrackBar

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an application using ASP .NET DevExpress controls. I have a ASPxTrackBar in a page. If I click "-" or "+" the slider decrements or increments it's value, which is OK. But now the ASPxTrackBar also got focus. If using the mouse wheel for scrolling the control changes value (because it has got focus). I would like the control to only change value when clicking "-" or "+", not through any other events.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the mouse wheel will not change the value of the ASPxTrackBar when it has focus you can use:

```
    <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="ASPxTrackBar1" runat="server" AllowMouseWheel="False">
```